# Close an window on PyQt4 without closing the others ones

Tags: python, pyqt4

My program opens another window from it, but, after used, I want this window to be closed automatically. Is that possible?

I've already tried using `sys.exit()` but this closes all my windows and I just want to be closed a specific one.

EDIT:
In my main window, I've a button that calls my other window with this function:

```
    from RPG_Changes import run as change
    class Ui_RPG_Roll(object):
        (...)
        def yes(self):
            change(self.dices)
        (...)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        RPG_Roll = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_RPG_Roll()
        ui.setupUi(RPG_Roll)
        RPG_Roll.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And in the window that is called, I've some data process, but basically this is the code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtTest
import dice_roll    #this is a function that I created that rolls dices 
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow, dados):
    (...data process...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow,dados)
    MainWindow.show()
    ui.sistema()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def run(dices):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow,dados)
    MainWindow.show()
    ui.sistema()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: did you try `.close()` ? without code example we cannot help you

Comment: I've tried `self.close()` in the end of data process and got a error: 

`self.close()
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'close'`